# Tried to make a simple adder in c++.Compiled successfully but the output is wrong

Tags: c++, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

created NOT,AND,OR and XOR functions(using NAND) then created the 'adder_prim' and  'adder_carry' functions for the primary output and the carry. Used the standard full adder circuit and put it in a loop(10 cycles so should be able to add til 2031).

entered the input in the code itself(X is 139,Y is 74) just to see if it's working properly or not.

instead of 216(correct ans) it's coming 196 and i have no clue why.

```
int NAND(int i,int j)
{
    int A;
    A=((i==1)&&(j==1))?0:1;
    return A;
}

int NOT(int i)
{
    int A=NAND(i,i);
    return A;
}

int AND(int i,int j)
{
    int A=NOT(NAND(i,j));
    return A;
}

int OR(int i,int j)
{
    int A=NAND((NAND(i,i)),NAND(j,j));
    return A;
}

int XOR(int i,int j)
{
    int A=OR(AND(i,NOT(j)),AND(NOT(i),j));
    return A;
}

int adder_prim(int,int,int);
int adder_carry(int,int,int);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int Z[10];
    int C=0;

    int X[]={0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1};
    int Y[]={0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0};

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        Z[i]=adder_prim(X[i],Y[i],C);
        C=adder_carry(X[i],Y[i],C);
    }

    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        cout <<Z[j];
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}

int adder_prim(int a,int b,int c)
{
    int O=XOR(XOR(a,b),c);
    return O;
}

int adder_carry(int a,int b,int c)
{
    int C=OR(AND(XOR(a,b),c),AND(a,b));
    return C;
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: What did the debugger tell you?

Comment: `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])` means you have a good integrated debugger. My advice is to spend 20 minutes and learn how to single step through your code looking at your variables. My second advice is to simplify your example for the debug. Make X and Y hold a 3 or 4 bit number instead. That may help your debugging since there are less steps. While you step through the code compare the result to a result you manually computed on paper and pen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the least significant bit first, not the most significant bit:

```
for(int i=9;i>-1;i--)
{
    Z[i]=adder_prim(X[i],Y[i],C);
    C=adder_carry(X[i],Y[i],C);
}
```